# Defining the sum in the integers rigorously

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

My question is:  Am I right with this definition of the sum in the integers?.

Well in class we covered the definition of the integers knowing the natural numbers as follows:

$$\mathbb{Z}=\{(a,b):a \in \mathbb{N}, b\in \{0,1\} \}$$

And then we had an example of the sum that we were asked to define:

$$(3,1)+(4,1)=(7,1)$$

$$(4,0)+(3,0)=(1,0)$$

And I think that then I can define the sum as follows:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a+b := (a+b,1)$ and if $a<0$ or $b<0 $ and $a<b$ or $b<a$, we define $a+b := (a-b,0)$

Then Am I right? or how can I improve my definition? thanks in advance for the help :) a lot

Comment: What does $b$ represent? Sign?  In which case your second example sum seems wrong...

Comment: yes it represents the sign but they were examples given by the teacher :)